# Scope of a variable. Internal working basic

Tags: c, memory-management

This is a very basic question about the scope of a variable suppose. I have the fiollowing code:

```
int main()
{
    int *p;
    p=func();
    printf("%d",*p);
    return 0;
}

int *func()
{
   int i;
   i=5;
   return &i;
}
```

My question

- The scope of i is finished in `func()` but, since I am returning the address of `i` will I be able to access and `print`5 in `main()`?
- If not, why? does the compiler puts a garbage value in that address space (I don't think this is done).
- What actually it means by **`the scope of a variable is ended`** ? Also does the memory allocated to `i` is freed when its scope ends?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Scope** of the variable is the region where it can be accessed.
**Lifetime** of the variable is the time till when the variable is guaranteed to exist.

In your case **lifetime** of `i` is within the function not beyond it. It means `i` is not guaranteed to exist beyond the function. It is not required to and it is **Undefined Behavior** to access a local variable beyond the function.

> **The scope of `i` is finished in `func()` but, since I am returning the address of `i` will I be able to access and print `5` in `main()`?**

You might, but it is Undefined Behavior. So don't do it.

> **If not, why? does the compiler puts a garbage value in that address space (I don't think this is done)**

The compiler may put whatever it chooses to in that location, once the function returns the address location is holds an **Indeterminate** value.

> **What actually it means by the scope of a variable is ended ? Also does the memory allocated to `i` is freed when its scope ends?**

`i` is a automatic/local variable and all automatic variables are freed once the scope `{`,`}` in which they are declared ends. Hence the name automatic.

Answer (score 2):

It is *undefined behaviour* to access a variable after it has gone out of scope. This means it is not possible to say what will definitely happen. In the posted code, `5` might be printed, some other value may be printed or some other behaviour may occur (access violation for example).

Answer (score 2):

Behaviour in your example is undefined.  Your `printf` probably will output 5 but that'd be down to luck rather than good design.

In this case, when the scope of the variable is ended, further function calls may reuse the stack address `&i` changing the value your `p` variable points to.

Answer (score 2):

No, accessing a variable that has gone out of scope leads to undefined behavior. The storage where thev variable used to be has been reclaimed, so you're likely to overwrite something else which can lead to crashes or just unpredictable behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Your function will probably print 5, but you should never do this.  It's undefined behavior since your program no longer owns the location pointed to by the pointer your return (in other words, your program no longer owns `i`).

Basically each time a function is called, the stack pointer is pushed down to accommodate the new stack frame.  When the function call ends, the stack pointer is raised back up.  This means that if a different function were to be called, it would have overlapping the same stack space as the previous function call.

To illustrate this a little better, consider this:

```
int main()
{
    int *p;
    p=func();
    printf("%d\n",*p);
    func2();
    printf("%d\n",*p);
    return 0;
}

int *func()
{
   int i;
   i=5;
   return &i;
}

void func2()
{
    int i = 1;
}
```

There's a pretty good chance that the output would be 5 1.  This is because the second call will reuse the same stack space.

(Note that above code snippet is *horrible* -- you should never do something like that -- it's undefined behavior and highly implementation dependent.)

---

To answer your questions directly:

> The scope of i is finished in func() but, since I am returning the address of i will I be able to access and print5 in main()?

No.  You *can*, but you shouldn't.  Such is the beauty of C.  Depending on the compiler/OS/etc it might output 5, or it might output random garage.

> If not, why? does the compiler puts a garbage value in that address space (I don't think this is done).

The space used for local variables is reused.  The first half of the answer hopefully illustrated how this works.  (Well, how it *typically* works.)

> What actually it means by the scope of a variable is ended ? Also does the memory allocated to i is freed when its scope ends?

[Stack based memory allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation) is what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: above code snippet is _horrible_ . I know that I just made this up now because I wanted more insight about the scope. Thanks for answering. +1